# From which page request generted for Devise login on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am working on an app in which there is a model **User** with roles **member** and **Admin**.

As per requirement, I have to made two separate login pages for roles of Admin and Member.

with `http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_login`

it goes to admin login page and with

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

it goes to member login page.

Somehow I managed to route according scenerio, after sign_in and sigout to respective admin panel or normal website for member.

But Now there is issue that when login fails it redirect it to `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in` even if in admin case.

Is there a way that I can know, From where this request is generated either from

`/admin` or `/users/sign_in` ?

So that I can redirect them to respective page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try like this: 
create a class on lib folder and overwrite devise failure

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp


   def redirect_url

    if request.referrer.include? new_user_session_path.split("/").last
       new_user_session_path
    else
       admin_login_path
    end
   end

  def respond
    if http_auth?
     http_auth
   else
     redirect
   end
 end
```

And put this config/initializers/devise.rb

```
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
```

put below line at config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```